# MySQL Remote Connection Issues

Tags: mysql, wordpress, remote-access

I've just learnt the basics of MySQL to allow me to upload tables onto my Wordpress site through wpdatatables. However, I can't for the life of me work out how to get a remote access connection working. There is plenty of literature and forum posts out there to help with this and I've tried a number of way but I haven't had any success.

I've created privileges for a user called morts81 using the code below:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'morts81'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then I've opened up the my.cnf file to ensure that the bind.address line is removed, however, I don't have a bind.address line so I imagine that isn't an issue.

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
```

Then finally I try and check the connection from inside the wpdatatable plug-in for Wordpress and I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

I've also tried replacing localhost in the wpdatatables input with 127.0.0.1 which seems to be recommended on some forums but I get a separate error then:

[image]

Would appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The socket you specified is different in your config file to start the mysql server. If you can connect to the socket as shown in first error message, use the below socket configuration

> socket      = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

For the 2nd error, see if your mysql server is accessible from the server/service datatables is running on.

Comment: I've tried changing the socket configuration in the my.cnf file to match the image above (specifically adding \lib in) but still get the same error.

Comment: did you restart the mysql server after changing the my.cnf?

Comment: Yeah I did, didn't help unfortunately.